# G-Sync option in NVIDIA Control Panel dissappears intermittently

Tags: mac, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming, g-sync

Firstly, I hope I'm asking this question on the right SE website. While this could be Mac related, I don't think so, which is why I'm here and not on Ask Different.

I have built a Windows 8.1 gaming machine on a 2009 Mac Pro, upgraded to 5,1. I'm using a flashed GTX 980 connected via display port to an Acer X34 Predator. For months, I've been using G-Sync and it has worked flawlessly. For the last few weeks, however, G-Sync keeps getting disabled and when I go into the NVIDIA Control Panel, the option doesn't even show.

I followed [these instructions](http://www.overclock.net/t/1529053/g-sync-option-is-not-there-anymore-what-happened), which basically say turn everything off, disconnected then reconnect everything, and then turn it back on and voila! G-Sync is back! However, it keeps intermittently going away.

Thinking it might be a video driver issue, I rolled-back to the previous version, but that didn't bring it back until I perform the steps above.

Since posting this question, I have noticed that **everytime** I start Windows from a cold start, I loose my G-Sync setting in NVIDA Control Panel. Now my routine is while in Windows, if I just remove the DP cable and reconnect it, the setting comes back.

Any idea what might be causing me to loose my G-Sync features?